# how to change timeout function to close on click?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code for auto hiding a message,

```
setTimeout(function () {
document.getElementById('err').style.display = 'none';
}, 5000);
```

I need to modify this code so that when I click a button it closes on click.

Below is the HTML code for the `div`:

```
<div class='alert alert-warning alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
  <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'
  aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
  <h4 id=err>Mail not sent</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to close the div......!

Comment: Make a `function` and call it that function on `click`.

Comment: replace `button` with link `<a>` as bootstrap provide default functionality to close alert message. Do like this `<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do like

```
$('.alert .close').click(function(){
    $('.alert-dismissible').fadeOut();
});
```

Call bind `click` event of your Alert and `fadeout` your alert `div`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.close').click(function(){
        $('.alert-dismissible').fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>
```